# Abnormal main.m crash

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

In my iOS app, I keep getting crash reports like this one.

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000018d805014 __pthread_kill + 4
1   libsystem_c.dylib 0x000000018d7799c4 abort + 136
2   libc++abi.dylib 0x000000018d2451b0 abort_message + 128
3   libc++abi.dylib 0x000000018d25ec04 default_terminate_handler() + 300
4   libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000018d26c820 objc_terminate() + 120
5   libc++abi.dylib 0x000000018d25b5d4 std::__terminate() + 12
6   libc++abi.dylib 0x000000018d25b640 std::terminate() + 56
7   libdispatch.dylib 0x000000018d6c29b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 32
8   libdispatch.dylib 0x000000018d6c75e8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 992
9   CoreFoundation 0x000000018e7b90c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
10  CoreFoundation 0x000000018e7b6cdc __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
11  CoreFoundation 0x000000018e6e6d94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
12  GraphicsServices 0x0000000190150074 GSEventRunModal + 96
13  UIKit 0x000000019499f44c UIApplicationMain + 204
!   14  MyAppNameHere 0x000000010007b090 main (main.m:33)
15  libdyld.dylib 0x000000018d6f559c start + 0
```

The strange thing is that none of this exists within my code except for the main.m. All other threads in my application don't have anything related to either. This crash appears to only happen for a fraction of a percent of my users, so I am not sure where to even start looking.

Answer (score -1):

The question as it is formulated right now is not answerable, because it is missing necessary information. See e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) for an explanation of how to obtain a real backtrace and how to obtain a "crash reason". Without following the recommended steps for debugging crashes every crash of an iOS-app looks exactly the same as the crash you just provided.

In order to get a real/useful backtrace, you need to set an exception breakpoint in Xcode.